# Is there a way to force AppKit to include my borderless NSWindow subclass in the Window menu?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I have a borderless `NSWindow` subclass that I use as part of a document based application. I have not been able to find a way to get it included in the Window menu. Calling `setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:` when the window is created has no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-[NSApplication addWindowsItem:title:filename:]` and manually add the window to the Window menu. For instance:

```
YourBorderlessWindow *window = …;
[NSApp addWindowsItem:window title:[window title] filename:NO];
```

Comment: Tried this and it's exactly what I needed. AppKit handles removing the entry from the Window menu when my document window is closed, so just adding the line of code in your example takes care of my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This also works great to keep an menu item for a window after it's been closed (i.e. your app keeps running in the background without a window). Just put it in your app delegate's windowShouldClose.